# Make a button fade out when another button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm kind of new here so don't judge too harshly lol.  I've created two buttons, and I want to make it to where when I click one, the other fades to grey. I am making a weather app and when the user switches from Fahrenheit to Celcius I want the button for Fahrenheit to become less opaque, and vice versa when switching back.  Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my jQuery for it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Fahrenheit').click(function() {
        $('#Celcius').fadeTo("fast", $('#celcius').css("opacity") == "1"?"0.5":"1");
        $('#Fahrenheit').fadeTo("fast", $('#Fahrenheit').css("opacity") == "1"?"1":"1");
    });
    $('#Celcius').click(function(){
        $('#Fahrenheit').fadeTo("fast", $('#Fahrenheit').css("opacity") == "1"?"0.5":"1");
        $('#Celcius').fadeTo("fast", $('#Celcius').css("opacity") == "1"?"1":"1");
    });
});
```

Comment: How does your HTML look like ?

Answer (score 0):

This may give you what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Fahrenheit').click(function() {
    $('#Celcius').animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, "fast");
    $('#Fahrenheit').animate({ opacity: 1 }, "fast");
  });

  $('#Celcius').click(function(){
    $('#Celcius').animate({ opacity: 1 }, "fast");
    $('#Fahrenheit').animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, "fast");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
<style>
    .btn-weather{
        transition: opacity 0.5s;
    }
    .btn-faded{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>
<button id="Farenheit" class="btn-weather">Farenheit</button>
<button id="Celsius" class="btn-weather">Celsius</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Farenheit').click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-faded');
            $('#Celsius').addClass('btn-faded');
        });
        $('#Celsius').click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-faded');
            $('#Farenheit').addClass('btn-faded');
        });
    });
</script>
```